# .NET Outlook Default folder free space (Quota Information)

Tags: email, outlook, interopservices

Is there any way to read via  **Microsoft.Office.Interop** free space left in default Mailbox ?

(So the same info what is displayed in Outlook's down left corner - as shown below)

[image]

Comment: I've found this  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/982997/mailbox-quota-information-is-not-displayed-on-the-status-bar-in-outloo
- but still no much luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to read the following properties using `Store.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty()`:

1. `PR_QUOTA_RECEIVE` (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x341C0003`)
2. `PR_PROHIBIT_RECEIVE_QUOTA` (DASL name  `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x666A0003`)
3. `PR_QUOTA_SEND` (DASL name  http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x341B0003)
4. `PR_PROHIBIT_SEND_QUOTA` (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x666E0003`)
5. `PR_QUOTA_WARNING` (DASL name http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x341A0003)
6. `PR_STORAGE_QUOTA_LIMIT` (DASL name : `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3FF50003`)
7. `PR_MESSAGE_SIZE_EXTENDED` (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E080014`)